# Microsoft Jet Database could not find Object

Tags: delphi, ado

I am trying to Migrate my Software from Windows 2008r2 to Windows 2012.

I created using odbc32 the Datasource Hegla ( Version Paradox 5.x ) , the Network Directory was changed to c:\Database .

Then from Delphi I do the connection string like this :

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=Hegla;Mode=ReadWrite;Initial Catalog=C:\database\augustdorf\hegla-lager;
```

Then if I try to open the Query, i get the error : The Microsoft Jet Database engine could not find the object Glasdaten

The query itself looks like this

```
select ArtikelNr as RemoteArtNr,Name,Höhe as Hoehe,Breite,Staerke,Mindestmenge as Bestellbestand,
count(c2.Glaszaehler) as Bestand,c2.BockNr
from Glasdaten c1
left join Lagerdaten c2 on c1.Glaszaehler=c2.Glaszaehler
group by ArtikelNr,Name,Höhe,Breite,Staerke,Mindestmenge,c2.BockNr
order by Name
```

and I have following files here :

```
C:\Database\Augustdorf\Hegla-Lager
Glasdaten.db
Lagerdaten.db
Pappen.db
```

Any idea why is this working on Windows 2008r2 , but no longer on Windows 2012 ?
What am I missing here ?

Regards
Robert

Comment: If you use the connection string editor in Delphi (or the OS UDL editor) what happens when you click the Test Connection button?

Comment: Connection Succeeded . As I said before , It works on Windows 2008r2 and Windows 10 ... and on Windows 2012 (makes no sense ) . I created a small program now where I can enter the Connection String Manually, I tried moving the files left and rights. It seems like it cannot access the file . But the error is not helping much .

Comment: I must be missing some driver or something , but I have no idea what . On Windows 2008r2 I installed no extra drivers. On Windows 10 I have Delphi and BDE installed.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out . BDE 5.11 was missing. This was in fact installed on Windows 2008r2 , but since the installer is really old it was not visible in Add Remove Programs, which led me to believe it was not installed.

Only after checking c:\Program Files(x86)\Borland\BDE folder ... did I realize that it was indeed installed.

Now only one minor problem exists . It seems like I need to Run the Application As Administrator to have enough rights ...  but that is another question/answer.

thank you.

Comment: I must say, I hadn't noticed until a couple of weeks ago that the MS Docs specifically state that the BDE is required in order for their drivers for dBASE and Paradox to work